# EE pagination how to set limit and total rows

Tags: pagination

How can I set total row count in pagination using `exp:channel`. Hope limit will limit the result per page.

How can we set the total row limit?

Answer (score 3):

To display the total rows across all the pages of your pagination, you use `{absolute_results}` which can be [**found here in the EE Docs**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#absolute-results).

> This variable will always display the absolute total number of results
>   that are returned by the tag, regardless of pagination.

---

The `limit=""` parameter is used to show a set number of entries per pagination page. [**Docs here**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#limit).

> This parameter limits the number of entries on any given page. The
>   limit will default to 100 entries if a value is not specified. If you
>   are using pagination then this will determine the number of entries
>   shown per page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how can i pass this row limit to exp channel. I want to get first 10 results showing 3 per pagination. We can pass limit="3" to pagination. But how to limit the total rows to 10 while using exp channel ?

Comment: Never knew of {absolute_results}! Great to know. Thanks  Anna! :)